# how to reference code in Markdown?

Tags: css, html, markdown, jekyll

*I write markdown file mainly for my jekyll blog, so liquid method is okay*

When inserting raw HTML code in to markdown. The whole markdown code page seems ugly and confused. And it will be difficult to modify days later.

So can I just make some of code be reference-style. To be more specific, **put the raw HTML code at the bottom of the markdown code page and just use the [...] at the original paragraph**. Just like the link and image reference-syntax.

#### origional code here

- para1
- para2

< a href="if there is a long long boring HTML link here but I want to put it at the bottom" />

- para3

### what I want to do is here

- para1
- para2

[ a brief reference code ]

- para3

< a href="there is still a long long boring HTML link here but I had it put at the bottom" />

Comment: And how would you reference code?  There is no need to reference code.   [Markdown Docs](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode)

Comment: By "inline HTML" do you mean escaped HTML that is rendered as entities, or do you mean raw HTML used to modify the structure of the text?

Comment: @Dai yes you a right, I mean I want to modify the structure of the text and differentiate the raw HTML and the markdown code.

Comment: why not use an editor and indent all the HTML code by 4 spaces before you insert it into the markdown file that way it renders inside a code block

Comment: It's a good way, but I want to do better. My idea can make the structure of the text clearly.

Comment: With some example code we can figure out what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for lacking of information, and now you may know what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown has no way of referencing content except for links:

```
- item 1
- item 2
- [boring_link]
- para3

[boring_link]: https://boring.com/link.html "description of boring link"
```

With Jekyll you can use Liquid's `capture` tag (even in .md files):

```
{% capture reference %}
… any html content …
{% endcapture %}
…
{{ reference }}
```

But this only works if you capture your content *first*.

I'm afraid, it's not possible to do exactly what you want; but depending on your actual HTML content there should be multiple alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question and it really works. Can you provide me more method to solve this question?

Comment: Well, the third one that comes to mind is using `{% include %}` which you already mentioned. Can you elaborate on the HTML tags you want to use?

Comment: Now I found two problem. First is if you use {% capture reference %} then you must put the **{% capture reference %} reference HTML code {% endcapture%}** before the** {reference}**. It's ugly. Now I usually put the capture at first. Second is if I use **{include}**, I should put the HTML file in to the _include folder, and it makes me Confuse between the reference HTML and other packages for my Jekyll site.

Comment: Mardown is designed for simplicity, which means that content doesn't end up somewhere else than it was in the code. If you could provide more details I'd be happy to suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: The example you gave in your question is actually already solved. I updated my answer to include the exact same example you gave. If you mean to reference anything else than a link you should rephrase your question.

Answer (score -1):

Jekyll has inbuilt syntax highlighting for displaying code, which will not only ensure it is rendered correctly (i.e. wrapped in `<pre>` and `<code>` elements) it also adds language specific styling.

For html highlighting you can use `{% highlight html %}`, for example:

```
{% highlight html %}
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <strong>Boom!</strong> I'm a code example.
    </div>
{% endhighlight %}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Surely it will make code beautiful. However, what I want to do is a bit like  **what the {% include %} do**.

Comment: sorry for lacking information, I had added a simple example for my question and now you may know what I want to do.